# I wanted to know the size of plaintext, key and ciphertext of the KP-ABE algorithm

Tags: abe

I have to present an ieee paper at my college, and I picked up a topic based on KP-ABE encryption and the paper doesn't have the size of plaintext, key and ciphertext in it

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Could you edit your question to include the link and name of the paper?

Comment: Key-Policy Attribute-Based-Encryption is a particular class of encryption, not one in particular. Thus the question is akin to asking the gross weight of a road vehicle without stating which.